# Convert a resultset into list of hashtables in Chicken Scheme

Tags: postgresql, scheme, chicken-scheme

what would be the easiest way to convert a resultset into a list of hashtables? I'm new to Scheme and would rather use a library function than roll my own. I'm using Chicken Scheme with the postgres egg. Thanks!

```
(use postgresql)

(define conn (connect '((dbname . "thedb") (user . "foo") (password . "secret") (host . "somehost"))))

(define rs (query conn "select id, name from users"))

(row-map print rs)

;(row-map ??? rs) ;what would take the place of the ??? here that would convert the row a hashtable so I end up with a list of hashtables?
```

Comment: what sjamaan said below. If however you definitely want a list of hashtables as a datastructure for your results,please share the reason :)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work like that.  row-map calls a procedure with the record
as positional arguments, so you only get them in a positional way.
Of course, if you know the positions, you can do something like this:

```lisp
(row-map* (lambda (id name)
            (alist->hash-table `((id . ,id) (name . ,name))))
          (query conn "SELECT id, name FROM users"))
```

This won't be very efficient, but it works well enough.  I wouldn't
advise you to use hash tables anyway, because they're not very
convenient to use.  I'd prefer alists any day of the week for short
lists; they're more efficient for a small set of keys.

But something else: why are you converting to a hash table?  It's more
efficient to loop through the result set once and perform your
computation inside that lambda.  Otherwise you're converting a complete
result set to a list of hash tables, and then the GC will collect the
result set.  Presumably you're going to loop over that list once more
(why else build up a list?).  So instead of doing that, just put your
processing code inside the above lambda and save you the extra traversal.